# Use mobile theme by default when browsing from Kindle e-readers

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, kindle

It would be much easier to use SE if kindle is identified as a mobile device.

User agent string for Kindle e-reader:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux armv7l like Android; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.2+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.2+ Kindle/3.0+

Comment: Until this is done, you can click the "mobile" link in the footer (left most side, below "feedback") to force the mobile web theme.

Comment: I found it just a minute ago after struggling since months. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Cheers, agree it's not trivial to find, but on the other hand most sites I know don't offer such option at all. (To force mobile view.)